# IE Toolbar Button User Login Not Persisted

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, toolbar, session-cookies

I have an IE toolbar button that pops up a small div on the existing web page and displays the images from the existing web page. The pop up is rendering html from, for example, www.abc.com/page1.aspx". The code in page1.aspx first checks if the user is logged in. If not then Response.Redirect to login.aspx. The problem is that once the user logs in and gets redirected back to page1.aspx the code acts as if the user is still not logged in.

The code on page1.aspx is:

```
if( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
  // do stuff
else
 Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
```

Currently it is an endless loop of logging in since HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is never true.

If I navigate to my site (ie. www.abc.com) using the IE browser, login, and then in another window use the IE button everything is ok; HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true. The problem only exists when the pop up asks me to login.

I'm stumped!